# reading the files and findout unique set of words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to the world of python/or programming in general.
I have a folder which consist of two .txt files. I want to read the files and create a data structure to store all unique words in those files. This what I have written,

```
import glob
import errno
path = '/path/to/my/files/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)

for name in files:
    try:
        with open(name, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
            f.read()
    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise
```

But I dont know how to modify the program to find the unique words. I would appreciate if you could guide me. Thank you.

Comment: `open` by default opens and reads in text mode which requires it to know the right `encoding` of the files (the default `utf-8` is obviously wrong). The Python docs tell how to set the encoding as parameter of `open`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher . Thank you and I was able to fix it and edited my original post just before you comment. Could you give some insight,how to implement to find the unique words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may do this:

```
import glob
import errno
path = '/path/to/my/files/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)

unique = dict()

for name in files:
   try:
       with open(name, encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
           data = f.read()
           for word in data.split(' '):
               if word.strip():
                   unique[word] = word

    except IOError as exc:
        if exc.errno != errno.EISDIR:
            raise

print unique.keys()
```

Answer (score 2):

[Edited] Changed dictionary to set.

1. Use a set to save the words.
2. I recommend you to create a function that reads a file and then use it in your for.

For example:

```
term_list = set()

def unique_words(path+"filename.txt"):
    text = open(path+"filename.txt","r")

    for line in text:
        if line != '\n':
            line = line.strip().split(' ')
            for word in line:
                term_list.add(word)
return
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in the parameter list for `unique_words`.  No plus sign should go there.  Perhaps you meant simply `path`.  You should also comment that in addition to what was requested, you're counting the number of uses of each word.  The `else: continue` is superfluous.  Finally, you need to call the function you defined to make it a complete program.  Regardless, it's a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

try adding 'encoding="latin-1"' to the open function. So
   with open(name, encoding="latin-1") as f: